# Docker上で立ち上げたRailsアプリのソースを変更しても即時反映されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

#### 何について聞きたいのか（質問の概要）

DockerComposeで立ち上げたAPIモードのRailsアプリのソースを変更しても即時反映されない。

#### 目的

Docker上で立ち上げているrailsアプリのソース（ローカルにあります）の変更を即時反映させたいです。

Docker Compose up とdownをしないと、変更が反映されないので開発効率が非常に悪くなっております。

Windows 11
Rails 7.0.8
Ruby 3.1.4
Docker 25.0.2

#### 状況

- ローカルのソースがマウントされているか
- config/emvironment/developmentの内容
- WSLの再起動

これだと思われる対応を施してみたのですが、解決しませんでした。

#### どこまで調べて何が分かったか

ローカルで変更したソースはコンテナ上（Docker Desktop）で変更が確認されたので、ローカルのソースがボリュームとしてマウント自体はされていそうです。

なので、railsの設定かと推察し、同じ症状で困っている人の記事を確認しましたが解決せず、一日頭を悩ませております。

やったことと症状の詳細は [自分の技術ブログ](https://sousuke-neosoul.com/rails%ef%bc%97%e3%80%80docker%e3%80%80%e3%82%bd%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b9%e3%81%ae%e5%a4%89%e6%9b%b4%e3%81%8c%e5%8f%8d%e6%98%a0%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84/) にまとめました。

ソースはGitHubのapiディレクトリになります。

Composeファイルはapiの一つ上に存在します。

https://github.com/sousukegit/plants_demo_app_v2_root

大変お手数ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問に関連するコードはなるべく質問の本文に直接記載してください。今回の場合なら Composeファイルを載せるべきように思います。